# What is the subject of this sentence to which the complement is related?

Tags: subject-complement, attachment-ambiguity

In this sentence, what is the subject to which the subject-complement is referring to?

> This instruction provides the rules for sharing information originated by the Purchasing Department.

Are we talking about the `rules` issued by the Purchasing Department, or the `information` issued by the Purchasing Department?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand your question. But there's only one subject in the sentence: 'This instruction'.

Comment: So what is the name if the component `rules` and `Purchasing Department` ?

Comment: Based on the provided context I have to concur with the accepted answer. However, the question leaves me with a smidgen of doubt about the *actual* context. If this is an excerpt from a technical or, Heaven forbid, legal paper (e.g. documentation or contract), it would be entirely possible that it was simply poorly written. Perhaps a slightly expanded view of the sentence would illuminate the intent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see no subject complement in this sentence.

Here's how I parse it:

- The subject of the main clause is *This instruction*. (*This, by the way, is an odd expression: an* instruction *is ordinarily a single directive, not a document containing a number of directives.*)
- The verb in the main clause is *provides*.
- The direct object of *provides* is noun phrase *the rules for sharing information originated by the Purchasing Department*. That noun phrase is composed of

  - a determiner, *the*
  - a noun, *rules*
  - a preposition phrase, *for sharing information*, which acts as a complement of *rules*.
    *(Note that this is* not *a complement of the verb* provides; for *in this case is selected by* rules *to introduce the matter which* rules *concerns. The* for *PP as a complement of* provide *would have a quite different meaning, approximately "to assure that information is shared".)*
  - a passive participle phrase<sup>†</sup>, *originated by the Purchasing Department*. The participle-plus-agent-complement acts here as a modifier—an 'adjective' in traditional grammar. We usually call the noun which a modifier describes its ***head*** (an adjective or PP in predicative position describes its ***predicand***),<sup>‡</sup> not its subject.

In this case the head of *originated by the Purchasing Department* is ambiguous: the 'default' reading by position is that it modifies the closest nominal, *information*; but in practice careful writing cannot be assumed, so it may be intended to modify *rules*.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Some grammars would parse this as a "reduced relative clause"—that is, a relative clause from which the relativizer and copula have been deleted: *<s>which BE</s> originated by the Purchasing Department*.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>To tell the truth, I dislike both these terms; *head* is inconsistently employed, and *predicand* is sometimes used in ways which obscure the fundamental difference between a modifier and a predicate. I know of no term for the entity which an adjective or 'adjectival' phrase describes regardless of syntactic position.</sub>